# DNS name resolution not happening in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

We set-up the kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes. One as master and two are slaves. And installed zookeeper and active mq in the master node. When we see the logs after deploying our application it showing http://foo.bar.com:2181(active mq DNS name) can't access or reach. If we change that activemq domain name to IP address in a properties file, it works fine.

I think name resolution is not happening in kubernetes, can you help how can i get this work automatically? because i cant change the property file always when there is new deployment.

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.17.0 (0c01409)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service:  config-service
  name:  config-service
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 2146593647
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2146593647
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: config-service
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service:  config-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: CONFIG_DIR
          value: /tmp/work/
        - name: audit_file_path
          value: /tmp/work/logs/audit.log
        - name: spring_cloud_zookeeper_connectString
          value: 172.X.X.X:2181
        - name: cross_orgin_hosts
          value: http://172.X.X.X:3056;http://172.X.X.X:3056;http://172.X.X.X:3056
        image: nexus.repo.com:8098/config-service:1.1.0-2198
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name:  config-service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8088
          hostPort: 8088
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp/work/
          name:  config-service-claim0
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
         disktype: node1
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /tmp/CONFIG_DIR
          type: ""
        name:  config-service-claim0
status: {}

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: config-service
  name: config-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8088"
    port: 8088
    targetPort: 8088
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: config-service
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about your K8S objets ? Which kind of resources are you using ? Deployments ? Services ? A glimps of your descriptor will help.

Comment: Please post the yaml of your service and ingress. How did you deploy the services?

Comment: We are doing deployment through the Jenkins pipeline job. And resources am using you can find it in the above yaml file which is for deployment and service. We are not using ingress or nginx. We are not using nginx or ingress.

Comment: Where did you configure the url http://foo.bar.com:2181? Your service name is "config-service".

Comment: Recently we have done the k8s set-up to our application. In single node it works fine and when it comes to k8s am getting those name resolution issues. For that i have to log into zkui server and change those properties file manually from domain name to the IP. After that i'll execute the deployment files, it works fine. Do i need to change configuraion related things, plz suggest. And, i have installed zookeeper and amq manually in the master node(not docker or deployment)
Deploymnet procedure:-
1.Create docker images and push to nexus 2.zookeeper and schema creation 3.Deploying in the node

Comment: That foo.bar.com:2181 will be available in zookeper properties file while running the job it will load automatically. We didn't configure  that url is any deployment or service file.

Comment: Since you didn't configure the DNS, it will not work. You need to create a service for you active mq and configure zookeeper with the dns of your service. The config-service yaml provided don't have the port 2181. Please improve your post  providing details about you setup and how your application work.

Comment: ok thank you, i will do that.